# Assignment by reference with sum() in data.table() yields incorrect result

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table test with 3 columns: Year, ID, Count (see first 3 columns below). I want to add a fourth column to summarize across ID and Year like so:

```
setkey(test, Year, ID)
test[, annualCount := sum(Count), by=list(Year, ID)]
```

What I got looks weird: it seems that function [ automatically add 1 to my annualCount. For example, ID 210 with Y1 should give me 8 instead of 9.

Is it a bug in data.table?

```
    Year       ID    Count  annualCount
 1:   Y1      210        1            9
 2:   Y1      210        1            9
 3:   Y1      210        0            9
 4:   Y1      210        1            9
 5:   Y1      210        1            9
 6:   Y1      210        1            9
 7:   Y1      210        1            9
 8:   Y1      210        1            9
 9:   Y1      210        1            9
10:   Y1     3197        1            6
11:   Y1     3197        1            6
12:   Y1     3197        0            6
13:   Y1     3197        1            6
14:   Y1     3197        1            6
15:   Y1     3197        1            6
```

Update: I am using R version 2.15.0 (2012-03-30), but I installed data.table_1.8.6. When I installed this package, I got an warning that this version was build on 2.15.1. Is this the cause for the bug?

Update 2: I installed latest R (2.15.2 at this time), but it doesn't help. With the same dataset, 
if I call

```
  test1 <- test[, list(annualCount = sum(Count)), by=list(Year, ID)]
```

then I get the correct result. But if I call

```
test2 <- test[, list(annualCount = sum(Count, na.remove = T)), by=list(Year, ID)]
```

then [ automatically add 1 to my sum. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to replicate this dataset with this error from scratch.

Update 3: dput(test) output.

```
structure(list(Year = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Y1", "Y2", "Y3"), class = "factor"), 
               ID = c(210, 210, 210, 210, 210, 210, 210, 210, 210, 
                            3197, 3197, 3197, 3197, 3197, 3197), 
               Count = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0)), 
          .Names = c("Year","ID", "Count"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), 
          row.names = c(NA, -15L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7fb6dc000778>)
```

Thanks.

Comment: no bug for me, I get 8 and 5 with your data!

Comment: Thanks agstudy. I updated my question. BTW, when I try on another mock dataset, I couldn't replicate this bug. I am pulling my hair

Comment: :-) I am trying to install latest R to see if it can resolve my issue

Comment: I also get the correct answers. Clear your workspace and try again?

Comment: Hi Dwin. Thanks for the advice. Please see my Update 3.

Comment: What is `na.remove`? I thought the correct argument was `na.rm`?

Comment: Thank you so much, mrdwab. it was the bug that caused weird behavior. Please post your comment as answer, so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a problem with `data.table`, but rather, human error ;)

To replicate, here is some sample data. I've included some `NA` values to see the results of the `sum` function with and without the argument to remove `NA`s, which is `na.rm`, not `na.remove`:

```
set.seed(1)
test <- data.table(Year = rep("Y1", 15),
                   ID = c(rep(210, 9), rep(3197, 6)),
                   Count = sample(c(0, 1, NA), 15, 
                                  prob=c(.2, .65, .15), 
                                  replace=TRUE),
                   key = "Year,ID")
test
#     Year   ID Count
#  1:   Y1  210     1
#  2:   Y1  210     1
#  3:   Y1  210     1
#  4:   Y1  210    NA
#  5:   Y1  210     1
#  6:   Y1  210    NA
#  7:   Y1  210    NA
#  8:   Y1  210     0
#  9:   Y1  210     1
# 10:   Y1 3197     1
# 11:   Y1 3197     1
# 12:   Y1 3197     1
# 13:   Y1 3197     0
# 14:   Y1 3197     1
# 15:   Y1 3197     0
```

Before we create our new column, let's just do some aggregation to see what happens with the different options for `sum`.

```
test[, list(annualCount = sum(Count)), by = key(test)]
#    Year   ID annualCount
# 1:   Y1  210          NA
# 2:   Y1 3197           4
test[, list(annualCount = sum(Count, na.rm = TRUE)), by = key(test)]
#    Year   ID annualCount
# 1:   Y1  210           5
# 2:   Y1 3197           4
```

Now, create your new column, with the results you expected.

```
test[, annualCount := sum(Count, na.rm = TRUE), by = key(test)][]
#     Year   ID Count annualCount
#  1:   Y1  210     1           5
#  2:   Y1  210     1           5
#  3:   Y1  210     1           5
#  4:   Y1  210    NA           5
#  5:   Y1  210     1           5
#  6:   Y1  210    NA           5
#  7:   Y1  210    NA           5
#  8:   Y1  210     0           5
#  9:   Y1  210     1           5
# 10:   Y1 3197     1           4
# 11:   Y1 3197     1           4
# 12:   Y1 3197     1           4
# 13:   Y1 3197     0           4
# 14:   Y1 3197     1           4
# 15:   Y1 3197     0           4
```

Comment: Thanks again. I realize that sum(1, na.remove = T) yields 2. This is because R assume na.remove is a new logical variable with value T, and force it to 1 when input to SUM function.

Comment: @AdamNYC, I think there is also a package or two that might define `na.remove` so the error is understandable :)